# Safari: Can I tab through smart search field options?

Tags: safari

In Firefox, I can start typing in the search bar and it will bring up options from my history, bookmarks, etc., and I can tab through those options.

Safari's smart search field does something similar. I can type a keyword and see in the list of options it presents me an item I want, but I cannot seem to tab through the options it presents me. When I press tab, it shifts focus off of the search field on to something else. What I can do is  take my hands off the home row, look down at the keyboard, find the arrow keys, and arrow through the options, but this is tedious. This might come across as picky, but despite wanting to try it, this is a non-starter for me for Safari. Is there a way to tab through (or navigate through in some other way) Safari's smart search field options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a Tab alternative, you can use `ctrl-N` (next) and `ctrl-P` (previous) to move through the smart search field options without having to look down or remove your hands from the home row.